# Continuous bounds for uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:(X,d) \to (X',d')$ is a uniformly continuous function between metric spaces. Is there a continuous $g:[0,\infty[\to [0,\infty[$ with $g(0) = 0$ such that $g(d(x,y))\geq d'(f(x),f(y))$?

As a possible solution, let $g(\delta) = \sup_{d(x,y)<\delta} d'(f(x),f(y))$. This is well defined because of uniform continuity, and $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = 0$. Is this a continuous function?

I'm interested to see uniform continuity as a generalization of Lipschitz continuity, where the condition holds for linear $g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $g$ is clearly nondecreasing, but it need not be continuous.
For example if $X=X'=\mathbb Z$ with standard metric and $f$ the identity, we have that $g$ maps $[0,\infty)\to\mathbb N_0$, $r\mapsto\lfloor r\rfloor$.

Here's a method how you *can* obtain a continuos function as required:
Let $g_0$ be such that $g_0(n)=g(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$ and linearly interpolates between these points.
To get from $g_{m-1}$ to $g_{m}$, let $g_{m}(x)=\max\{g(x),g_{m-1}(x)\}$ for $x\in 2^{-m}\mathbb N_0$ and interpolate linearly inbetween.
Let $G(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} g_n(x)$.